# confusion with Node Set Function - 'ID'

Tags: xpath, node-set

[`Function: node-set id(object)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id)

> When the argument to id is of type node-set, then the result is the union of the result of applying id to the string-value of each of the nodes in the argument node-set.

I didn't get the above lines from the doc. May I have one example to understand the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure

Suppose your document uses an attribute idref="A B C" to contain a reference to the nodes with id="A", id="B", and id="C".

Then `id(//@idref)` will select all the nodes with id's that are referenced in any @idref attribute anywhere in the document.

Comment: Ok. so if it is `idref="AB C"`, then ?

Comment: Then it will find the nodes with id's "AB" and "C". It's a space-separated list.

Comment: Thanks sir for your help... may I have your email id,if you don't mind? As I sometimes got stuck in few points like above.May be sometimes at very basic one also. In that case I would email you,rather posting here. Because SO don't allow basic questions. Please sir...

Comment: You need to learn the protocol. It's easy to find out my email address, but if you try to ask me direct questions I will always reply saying you should ask on a forum such as StackOverflow. I'm not an unpaid personal tutor.

Comment: Hum.. but you are an expert on this domain. Thus I thought you would also help me. If you don't want..its OK :)